# Problems with do add_row and group_by. Need the group_by variable name in add_row

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Problem: I want to add_row using dplyr/tibble. I want to group the data by A in my example, and then add_row that contains the group name A and then a value for B.

The problem I am facing is trying to add the Group_by variable A in the column under A. No matter what I try it always comes back with an error or NA as the value in that column.

1. Reproducible example:

   ```
   example <- data.frame(A = sample(letters[1:3],10,replace = TRUE), 
                 B = sample(letters[24:26],10,replace = TRUE),
                 C = sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE))
   ```
2. Output of example data:

   ```
         A B C
      1  c y 2
      2  b x 3
      3  c y 1
      4  b y 1
      5  c z 1
      6  a x 1
      7  b x 1
      8  c z 2
      9  a y 3
      10 c y 1
   ```
3. Code I want to run.

   ```
   answer <- example %>%
     mutate(A = as.character(A),
            B = as.character(B)) %>%
     group_by(A) %>%
     do(add_row(., 
                B = "ADDED",
                C = "ADDED"))
   ```
4. Output of the data:

   ```
           A     B     C
     1     a     x     1
     2     a     y     3
     3  <NA> ADDED ADDED
     4     b     x     3
     5     b     y     1
     6     b     x     1
     7  <NA> ADDED ADDED
     8     c     y     2
     9     c     y     1
    10     c     z     1
    11     c     z     2
    12     c     y     1
    13  <NA> ADDED ADDED
   ```
5. So in the output of the data, where there is NA I would like it to say the group name (a,b, or c)

I have tried putting just the group variable name there, it does not work throws an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add it directly within `do`.

```
example %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    do(add_row(., 
               A = unique(.$A),
               B = "ADDED",
               C = "ADDED"))
```

Or use `tidyr::fill` at the end. Because it is filling the grouping variable you must `ungroup` first.

```
library(tidyr)

example %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    do(add_row(.,
               B = "ADDED",
               C = "ADDED")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    fill(A)

# A tibble: 13 x 3
       A     B     C
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     a     z     2
 2     a     x     1
 3     a     y     2
 4     a ADDED ADDED
 5     b     y     1
 6     b     z     1
 7     b ADDED ADDED
 8     c     z     2
 9     c     y     2
10     c     z     2
11     c     y     2
12     c     z     1
13     c ADDED ADDED
```

Comment: aosmith, Your second answer worked for the real dataset/problem I had. When I used the .$A for my real dataset, it created 2 copies of the add_row. Not sure why it did not, however, the second solution you provided worked just nicely. Thank you for the help! I got to learn about fill()

Comment: @MattD I forgot `unique` in the first option, it should work better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(zoo)

df=read.table(text='A     B     C
              1     a     x     1
              2     a     y     3
              3  NA ADDED ADDED
              4     b     x     3
              5     b     y     1
              6     b     x     1
              7  NA ADDED ADDED
              8     c     y     2
              9     c     y     1
              10     c     z     1
              11     c     z     2
              12     c     y     1
              13  NA ADDED ADDED',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$A=na.locf(df$A)

> df
   A     B     C
1  a     x     1
2  a     y     3
3  a ADDED ADDED
4  b     x     3
5  b     y     1
6  b     x     1
7  b ADDED ADDED
8  c     y     2
9  c     y     1
10 c     z     1
11 c     z     2
12 c     y     1
13 c ADDED ADDED
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

example <- tibble(A = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                  B = sample(letters[24:26], 10, replace = TRUE), 
                  C = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(C = as.character(C)) %>% 
  arrange(A)

to_be_added <- example %>% distinct(A) %>% cbind(B = "ADDED", C = "ADDED")

bind_rows(example, to_be_added) %>% arrange(A)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#>        A     B     C
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     a     z     2
#>  2     a     y     1
#>  3     a ADDED ADDED
#>  4     b     x     1
#>  5     b     z     1
#>  6     b     z     1
#>  7     b     y     3
#>  8     b     y     1
#>  9     b     y     1
#> 10     b ADDED ADDED
#> 11     c     y     1
#> 12     c     z     1
#> 13     c ADDED ADDED
```